# Best schema to combine data from multiple tables?

Tags: database, t-sql, database-design, relational-database

I need some assistance from the database people here.  I need to be able to store sports statistics for games that a sports player plays and then display that data sequentially in a timeline (sort of the player's sports career).  A player can play one or more sports.

Here are two schemas I came up with, but both have issues:

**Idea #1:** Directly link each statistic to a player.

[image]

**Benefits to this idea:** It uses relational theory and properly links the tables with relationships.

**Problems with this idea:** Seems like there could be some issues with working with data from a lot of different Statistics tables like this.

---

**Idea #2:** Use an intermediary table to link the Player with their statistics.

[image]

**Benefits to this idea:** It would be very easy to query the PlayerStatistic table and get an ordered list of games that the player played.  The sport for each row would be very easy to identify due to the table's name being in the row.

**Problems with this idea:** no relationship can between the PlayerStatistic table and its child statistic tables (i.e. BaseballStatistic, FootballStatistic).  This kind of throws relational theory out the window.

---

Which idea would you use? Or is there an even better way to accomplish this goal?

---

If it matters, I am using SQL Server 2014

---

Edit: this idea was suggested.  What do you think?

[image]

Comment: A much better design is to have a games table with baseball, basketball, football, soccer, etc. as rows in it with IDs and have the Statistics table have foreign keys to player and game.

Comment: Hi Anand, I added a third diagram to the post above.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Slight difference, relationship goes straight from player to statistic instead of through game. So Statistic has both PlayerID and GameID.

Comment: How would you enforce data grouping, however?  I mean if for every Baseball game a player is required to have 5 separate statistics, how would that requirement be enforced?

Comment: 2 is bad and write a test select statement for 3.

Comment: @Paparazzi - I'm tempted to use 1, to limit complexity.  Any thoughts on it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that this is an instance of class-subclass or, if you prefer, type-subtype.  Baseball statistic and Football statistic both appear to be specialized subclasses of statistic.  You second idea very much resembles a certain technique, known as class table inheritance, which you can look up on the web.  It's not quite the same as other instances I've seen in that player statistic isn't quite like a superclass, but it's close.

There is one added technique you can use to help you relate baseball satistic and football statistic to player statistic.  It's called shared primary key.  Here, baseball statistic ans football statistic would each get, as their primary key, a copy of the id field of player statistic.  This not only establishes the relationship, but it also constrains each of the two relationships to be one-to-zero-or-one.  You would have to make this copy programatically, whenever you added a new player statistic.

Using this design, you could also accommodate a player who played both baseball and football, if you ever wanted to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with second choice. Remember whenever you are having a many to many relationship, create a mapping table and when there is one to many mapping just go with primary foreign key relation ship.